# Get fields in REST response for 0 records found

Tags: rest-api, query

[image]I need to display fields to the user for query requests where there are 0 records found. So for example if I have **SELECT id, status,subject,AccountID, Description , CreatedDate FROM Task** I want to display these fields as metadata  to user in a table format with empty rows below instead just some message like "0 records found". Just like in the developers console in the screenshot attached. What I dont want to do is any kind of parsing in my code to retrieve these fields. I was just wondering if there is a way perhaps some flag to get these in my response. I appreciate the help.

I get only this back in my REST response in this case:
{
"totalSize": 0,
"done": true,
"records": []
}

Comment: Out of the box - no, you'll have to parse the response.

Comment: do you mean request?  I dont get those fields in the response for 0 records

Comment: There's no flag in the request that will change the format of the response. Given a 200 response status code, you'll need to parse the response body to see if 0 (or more) records came back.

Comment: I know I need to parse the response but I dont get the values I need back ie the fields/metadata  back . I attached the developers console screenshot of what I am trying to achieve in my application.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no official way to do this in Salesforce for a query that returns no records. Dev Console is parsing the query but there's no API for this. The KISS solution is to keep track of the fields you're adding to the query. You could try a [SOQL parser](https://github.com/paustint/soql-parser-js) that someone wrote in JS. Caveat emptor.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: one more thing though because I am actually rewriting our current solution and there are issues just keeping fields that are being added to the query so for example if I ran following  query SELECT
Id,
AccountId,
Contact.Account.Name
FROM Contact
the response will not bring back a field Contact.Account.Name but Account.Name  so the metadata wouldnt match or for example if you have custom relationships or tables this gets different values back . Example again would be

Comment: Select
Opportunity__r.Account.Name
,Opportunity__r.Account.Account_Owner_Name__c
,Opportunity__r.Account.Owner.UserRole.Name
,Opportunity__r.Account.Owner.Name
FROM Order__c

Comment: This is not querying the Opportunity__r. object but the  Opportunity   "Opportunity__r": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Opportunity",
                    "url": "/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0061v00000hFLNTAA4"
                },